# Change of variable in Hardy Littlewood proof

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is part of a proof I try to understand.
Lets $Tf(x)$ be the Hardy littlewood maximal funtion,
$$Tf(x)  = \sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{B(r,x)} \int_{B(r,x)} f(y) dy$$ 
and $E_\lambda = \{y: |Tf(y) |> \lambda \}.$ Then

$$\|Tf\|_p^p = \int_0^\infty p \lambda^{p-1} \nu(E_\lambda) d\lambda$$
here 
This seems like some classical trick of variable change. I think I seen similar things before, can someone explain of prove that this "obvious" thing is holds true. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Fubini's Theorem, we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}} |Tf|^p dx &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_0^{|Tf(x)|} p \lambda^{p - 1} d\lambda dx  \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_0^{\infty} p \lambda^{p - 1} \chi_{\{|Tf(x)| > \lambda\}}(\lambda, x) d\lambda dx \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} p \lambda^{p - 1} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \chi_{\{|Tf(x)| > \lambda\}}(\lambda, x) dx d\lambda \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} p \lambda^{p - 1} m(E_{\lambda}) d\lambda
\end{align*}

as desired.

---

For a good reference, take a look at the last few sections of Chapter $8$ in Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis, where he studies distribution functions.

Comment: This was a beutifull! Thanks for the reference, will check that!

Comment: @Johan Glad to help. Rudin proves it in a slightly more general manner - namely if $\varphi$ is monotone, absolutely continuous on all intervals $[0,T]$, $\varphi(0) = 0$ and $\varphi$ is continuous at infinity, then $$\int_X (\varphi \circ f) d\mu = \int_0^{\infty} \mu\{f > t\} \varphi'(t) dt$$